# IF ELSE html helper in razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I will like to use IF ELSE statement in Razor view. Is it possible to use IF( html.helper ) then do something? Or any suggestion?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Question_ID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Type)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Question)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    @if(@Html.DisplayFor(m=> m[i].Type =="Info_Text") **
                    {
                        <td>
                              //DO NOTHING
                        </td>                
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Answer)
                    </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }

    </table>
```

Comment: did u tried the same? is it giving some error..post it

Comment: why you must use the if statement on the html.helper instead on the item in the model?

Comment: Any particular reason why you wouldn't just test `m[i].Type == "Info_Text"` instead of `DisplayFor`?

Comment: Hi all, i'm quite new to Razor and still figuring out. @DaveWard thanks your answer works! I though it must use together with html.helper.

Comment: @Edward.K: Don't worry, we're all still figuring some of it out. I added an answer with some extra info that might help clarify some of the issues around this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can test the value of `m[i].Type` directly:

```
@if (m[i].Type == "Info_Text") {
  <td></td>
} else {
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Answer)</td>
}
```

The reason you wouldn't test against the value of `DisplayFor` is that it returns an `MvcHtmlString`, not just a simple type like a `string` or `int`. You *could* do something like this if you ever find the need to compare to a `DisplayFor` some day (and hopefully this makes it all make a little more sense):

```
@if (Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Type) == new MvcHtmlString("Info_Text"))
```

Since you're in the process of learning MVC, you might also be interested in how you can customize the `EditorFor` helper to do this automatically: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to use DisplayFor? Do you have any particular reason?

How about if you use

```
if(Model[i].Type =="Info_Text")
{
<td>
    //DO NOTHING
</td>
}
```

Comment: This is what @DaveWard told in the comment. What you did different?